# Is it ok to pass a socket to a function as const?

Tags: c, windows, sockets, winsock, file-descriptor

Say I have a windows socket named `socket`. If `socket` was passed to a function which doesn't write to it. For instance say a function that sends a simple message/bytes to the client like `Hello you're connected to the server!`.
For example:

```
void send_hello(SOCKET socket, char* data) {
    send(socket, data, sizeof(data), 0);
}
```

Would it be safe to pass the socket as `const`? For example:

```
void send_hello(const SOCKET socket, char* data) {
    send(socket, data, sizeof(data), 0);
}
```

Something in my brain tells me I should be passing `socket` as `const` rather than passing it as writeable memory. I know sockets are file descriptors, so I'm obviously confused as to how they work and if they're always or ever written to. However my code works when passing `socket` as `const`.

My overall question is:

Is it ok to pass a variable with the type `SOCKET` object as `const`? Or should said `SOCKET` always be in writeable memory regardless of scope?

Comment: Check how socket is defined in you'r library WinSocks2. It should be something like `HANDLE` i.e.`void *` - so off cause you can pass it like const (and you'd better to).

Comment: That's what I thought because it's more secure.

Comment: Written memory - means it is allocated in the written memory region. See [VirtualAlloc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualalloc)

Comment: @VictorGubin In Winsock, `SOCKET` is a `UINT_PTR`, ie a pointer-sized integer.  It is not a `HANDLE`/`void*`

Comment: Note: 'send(socket, data, sizeof(data), 0);' would send only sizeof(a pointer), bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always safe to add top-level `const` to a function argument.  This is not even part of the function signature, it just tells the compiler that inside the function body you will not change the parameter to a different value; that in turn lets the compiler catch mistakes where you would reassign the parameter.

Note that when you call `send`, the first argument is receiving a `copy` of the argument `socket` (aka "pass by value").  So it makes no difference whether `socket` is or is not in writable memory.

Answer (score 0):

A `SOCKET` is just an integer (specifically, `SOCKET` is an alias for `UINT_PTR`, ie a pointer-sized unsigned integer), so it doesn't really matter in your example if you pass it as `const` or not, since you are passing it *by value*.  `send()` takes a `SOCKET` by non-const value, so your `SOCKET` is going to get copied around by value no matter what.

Pass your `socket` parameter by `const` if you want to, that just means your function can't assign a new value to the `socket` parameter.  It has nothing to do with the underlying socket resources that the `SOCKET` refers to.